# What's the best way to delete all directories except for one sub-directory?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I recently upgraded my hard drive to a 480 gig SSD (awesome improvement, by the way) and moved the 1TBhard drive over into the the 2nd bay.

Instead of trying to migrate the Windows install, I just remapped the second drive to D: and freshly installed Windows on the SSD.

However, my "old" installation of Windows 7 and junk are still present on that 1TB drive, alongside several directories which contain my media files (which I want to delete).

What is the most  efficient way to delete all the contents of the disk but ignoring a few select sub-directories? Are there any file management applications for this? Or perhaps is it better for me to run this from the console?

I have about 7 unique directories (none are sub-dirs of each other) that I want to save. The rest of the drive I'd like to use purely for data storage.

Comment: If you just want to select a few directories.  Just move those directories to another location, and delete the other files, this is much easier then trying to **NOT** delete them using a recursive function.

Comment: ...doh. That was a significantly better way of doing it. I did not even think of that. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I will gladly select it as the right one. Egg on face.

Comment: I will allow somebody who needs the reputation post that answer.